# Sort NSArray by other NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I have a NSArray called objects. This array could look like this:

```
[0]
   "name" => blaBlaBla
   "foo"  => b
   "bar"  => c

[1]
   "name" => bluBluBlu
   "foo"  => b
   "bar"  => c
```

I also have a NSMutableDictionary, which changes every second. This will look like this

```
['blaBlaBla']
   "sortValue" => 1

['bluBluBlu']
   "sortValue" => 4
```

I would like to present my data in the array in a UITableView. I would like to present it in the descending order of the NSMutableDictionary's "sortValue"

How can I do this. I've tried a NSSortDescriptor, but I can only get that to sort my NSMutableDictionary and not my NSArray.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSArray method `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` takes a block that compares two objects. You can write that block any way you want, including using a dictionary to look up the sort values for each element in the array.

If your sortValue dictionary is changing on a different thread then you'll need to copy it before sorting in order to avoid changing it out from under the sort process. If both the sorting and the changes to the dictionary take place on the main thread then there's no problem.